# googlechrome not working properly

Tags: google-chrome

My question is about google-chrome-stable. Most of the time it works, but I get this error when I try to sign in to www.slcolibrary.org.

[image: Error_1]

I put this in the command line:

```
google-chrome-stable
```

and got this screenshot:

[image: Error_2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Server Error' screen shot you posted has nothing to do with your computer or Google Chrome installation. It means, the software that runs the website you are trying to visit (www.slcolibrary.org in this case) has encountered an issue.

Comment: The Server Error screen shot happened as google chrome opened up, there was no further input when I when to the libraries website.